# does hotlinking prevention not work on my site?

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

I already tried many solutions suggested in the Web and on this site but the hotlinking prevention seems not working on my site.

I know very little about the rules of htaccess.

I have this `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes

php_value date.timezone 'Europe/Rome'

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<FilesMatch "\.user\.ini|info\.php|error_log">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysubdomain.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule [./]* index.php [L]
```

I inserted at the end of that file the code suggested in http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ https://other_img_url [L]
```

Then I tested an image url (e.g. `https://mysubdomain.mysite.com/img/mylogo.png`) in this page: http://altlab.com/hotlinkchecker.php but the image is always displayed so the hotlinking protection is not working.

I also tried to insert in the `.htaccess` only these lines, without empty lines, but it still doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ https://other_img_url [L]
```

I placed the file `.htaccess` in many directories:

```
root/
   .htaccess
   public_html/
       .htaccess
       img/
   mysubdomain/
       public_html/
           .htaccess
           img/
               mylogo.png
```

The site is working properly, so there is no syntax error in the `.htaccess` file.

My site is in a shared hosting, so I cannot access the server directly nor run some batch commands from command line (I also tried the code suggested by the hosting provider but without success).

What I'm making wrong?

There is something I missed?

Can there be anything on the server side that interferes with it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do the image URLs look like you want to get blocked?

Comment: @arkascha I edited the question. Sorry, I forgot it...

Comment: You should sort out the difference between `http` and `https` between actually requested URLs and your condition, but that is not the cause of what you describe here.

Comment: I suggest you enable rewrite logging and start debugging...

Comment: @arkascha can I do it without the permission to access the server configuration? (see my edit) My site is in a shared hosting.

Comment: Oh, that sort of hosting. No, no way then, sorry.

Comment: Another thing I would like to point out: in that "replacement image" you display you accuse the requesting user of hot linking. But that is wrong, since it actually is not the user who clicked a link of looks at a page containing the hot link. So you accuse the wrong person, not a very friendly thing to do...

Comment: @arkascha I don't understand your comment about "replacement image": maybe you commented in the wrong post? :)

Comment: Absolutely not, I referred to that image you use: `https://i.imgur.com/ZtXiCBw.gif`

Comment: @arkascha ah, ok I agree with you. I edit the question so the image is general.

Comment: @arkascha The hosting provider is not able to give me support... Can you help me to discover the cause of the problem? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean they are unable to support you? You pay them! They certainly should be able to. Otherwise you should consider changing your provider!

Comment: @arkascha I agree with you so I'm really thinking to change to DigitalOcean instead of mochahost... Precisely, their tool present in the cpanel inserted the hotlinking prevention code in my htaccesses at the end of the file but above there were already other rewrite rules with the [L] modifier so the next one will never be reached... Also their chat support didn't know how to write an htaccess file and they always ask me to provide to them my cpanel password to let them check and help me! O_o

Comment: There are two issues with your statement about the `[L]` flag: 1. that flag only has any effect of the rule it is specified for does get applied and 2. it does _not_ terminate the rewriting process, it only terminates the _current_ run! Note that once a rule has change the target of the request another run is started until no further changes occur. Read the documentation!

Comment: @arkascha thanks, where I can find an accurate documentation?

Comment: You mean you never even bothered to take a look into the documentation of the tool you use prior to asking here? Ouch  ;-)   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html  As always with OpenSource software the documentation is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.

Comment: @arkascha I seen that documentation before posting here, it says for `[L]`: "Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules." You said "2. it does not terminate the rewriting process, it only terminates the current run!" so it seems I wan't wrong, what did you mean with "current run"?

Comment: The flag immediately stops the current run through the rewriting rules. But as said: it starts again until the rules do not change anything any more. Current versions of the apache http server offer the additional `[END]` flag, that one indeed immediately terminates the whole rewriting process.

Comment: @arkascha thanks for your help! I sent an official complaint to the hosting provider and they solved the problem server side. Maybe there wasn't some setting that only them can change. Now it works with no changes in my .htaccess files! But I still doubt about their quality service because there be other hidden errors/problem in the server that I not already know...

Comment: OK, glad you finally solved your issue. Actually that does not sound too bad if they actually acknowledged the issue and invested into solving it. Many big hosting providers in the mass market would simply not react apart from  standard template reply.

Comment: @arkascha They say that they solved by doing this: now the requests/directives are processed directly by the web-server instead of being before processed by nginx. I don't know anything about that. It's a plausible reason or it hide a unprofessional behavior? thanks for your time spent to help me

Comment: Interesting. So they use a setup with two http servers, on behind the other. Most likely nginx is used as a frontend / load balancer server, apache as an application server. A ".htaccess" style file cannot be interpreted by nginx, so there are two options here: 1. they changed their frontend server configuration (unlikely) or they took your ".htaccess" style file and converted it into the nginx format. Which means that you cannot change it anymore yourself without them doing that step over and over again. That does not sound good. Maybe that is what you should try to get clear.

Comment: @arkascha I can still change the same .htaccess file contents and view the changes immediately without asking for them.

Comment: And the changes have effect? OK, then it most likely was option 1 above. Sounds OK then.

Comment: @arkascha many thanks :) have a good day!